# multiple MessageDispatcherServlet in Spring

Tags: spring-boot, servlets

I have urls `/a` to handle soap1.1 request and `/b` to handle soap1.2 request in my SpringBoot application.

Ideally if I can register 2 `MessageDispatcherServlet` then I can explicet set the MessageFactory to be a soap1.2 factory in one servlet and use default 1.1 in another.

But after the application is up, requests to `b` result in 404. I checked `actuator/mappings`, seems only `/a` are mapped, that explains the 404

[image]

But the code seems good, and I checked `actuator/beans` both 2 beans (`MessageDispatcherServlet`) are registered.

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean aDispatcherServlet(@Qualifier("a_servlet") MessageDispatcherServlet servlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/soap/a/*");
}

@Bean(name="a_servlet")
public MessageDispatcherServlet MessageDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext context) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(context);
    servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocation(true);
    return servlet;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean bDispatcherServlet(@Qualifier("b_servlet") MessageDispatcherServlet servlet) {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/soap/b/*");
}

@Bean(name="b_servlet")
public MessageDispatcherServlet MessageDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext context) {
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet(context);
    servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocation(true);
    return servlet;
}
```

Anyone has idea how could it be done?

Comment: Please post code as code, instead of images. The images are totally unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Per https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19605

I called `setName()` on `ServletRegistrationBean` the 2 beans have different names then both registered.